# I am waiting for a response from the server, but want to show some timeout message in the UI after 1 minute while waiting for the response

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I am waiting for a response from the server for adding a task to a list (this happens in the background), but want to show some timeout in the UI after 1 minute has passed with the message that the operation is taking longer than expected, the response from the server could be a success or a failure eventually.

```
Q.when(api.getTask(taskId))
        .then(function(data) {
            dispatch({type:'GET_TASK_REQUEST', data});   
        }).then(function() {
            Notify.showSuccess('Get task was a success');
            dispatch({type: 'GET_TASK_SUCCESS'});
        }).fail(function(error) {
            Notify.showError(error);
            dispatch({type: 'GET_TASK_FAILURE'});
        });

    setTimeout(() => {
        if(isLoading)
            dispatch({type: 'GET_TASK_TIMEOUT'});
    }, 60 * 1000);
```

Based on the GET_TASK_TIMEOUT action which is dispatched if the server has still not returned a response, I set the state to show a notification that the operation is taking longer time than expected in the UI. Is this approach correct? It is doing the job but I have not used timeout in this fashion before and I dont know if it is the right way to go about it.

Comment: why don't you use inline loader? call API from useEffect using async wait and show the loader or some message until you get data from API.

Comment: I am showing a loader in the UI while waiting for the response. What I want to do is, that if a certain time has passed, in this case, 60 seconds, I would just like to show a notification that it is taking time and to not cancel out.

Answer (score 0):

i will show you a example where i am using `fakePromise` with `20000ms` return time so if the time is greater then `10000ms` and the Promise didn't resolve yet it should show loading screen or whatever you want. I am using setInterval with `startDate` and `endDate` which update on each interval, and then we compare the 2 dates to check if it's greater than `10000ms` here's the code :

```
   const fetchData = async () => {
  try {
    const sDate = new Date();
    let endDate;
    const LoadingResponse = setInterval(() => {
      if (endDate && endDate.getTime() - sDate.getTime() > 10000) {
        setLoading(true);
        clearInterval(LoadingResponse);
      } else endDate = new Date();
    }, 1000);
    const data = await fakePromise();
    clearInterval(LoadingResponse);
    setData(data);
  } catch (error) {
  } finally {
    setLoading(false);
  }
};
```

and here the codeSandbox: [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/weathered-brook-c6hux?file=/src/App.js:337-883)